# Finding Vbe for a darlington pair?

Tags: darlington

I'm looking for guidance for a homework problem. I have invested several hours into it, and the feedback from the professor hasn't been constructive. I modeled the circuit with LtSpice to verify my hand calculations. The feedback from the professor was the Vbe for each transistor was 0.5V, and my spice model was wrong. This is my first microelectronics course to give everyone an idea of the knowledge base I'm working with. I have attached a pic of my calculations and Spice model. Thanks in advance for the guidance.

[image: Hand calculations]

[image: Spice model]

Comment: Since the collector currents in the two BJTs aren't the same, and assuming the BJTs are identical to each other, then it is impossible for both base-emitter voltage differences to be the same. A professor who tells you they must be the same should be replaced -- find another one.

Comment: Broadly speaking, given \$\beta=100\$ and assuming that the resistor doesn't drop much voltage for now, the collector current in \$Q_2\$ should be about 100 times that in \$Q_1\$. Therefore, there should be about \$V_T\cdot\ln\left(100\right)\$ or somewhere from \$115\:\text{mV}\$ and \$120\:\text{mV}\$ (depending on what you use for \$V_T\$) difference between them. Since \$x+x+120\:\text{mV}=1\:\text{V}\$ then \$Q_1\$'s \$V_{_\text{BE}}\approx 440\:\text{mV}\$ and \$Q_2\$'s  \$V_{_\text{BE}}\approx 560\:\text{mV}\$. It's just basic logic. Find someone else to teach you.

Comment: By the way, it's something to keep in mind that for small signal BJTs there is about \$60\:\text{mV}\$ per factor of 10 in the collector current. Since you have two orders of magnitude, not one, that means \$120\:\text{mV}\$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My model and calculations are an estimation, but I felt like my process was solid. Given the Vbes are lower than the 0.7 needed to be in the active region, would one of the transistors realistically be in cut off? Thus, implying equation 3 is not valid?

Comment: The two base-emitter junctions are clearly forward-biased. Q1 cannot be anything other than in active mode. And there is no way for Q2 to be cutoff. It might be saturated if its collector resistor were large enough. But not cutoff.

Comment: I've added a fleshed-out answer. Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: Only to note that this is not exactly what is called a "Darlington pair". To be so, Q1's collector should be connected to Q2's collector instead to Vcc as shown. As they say, a "magic smoke" can appear in your case:-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's make a reasonable simplification. We can always come back and check on it, later. Namely:

- Bypass \$R_1\$ to remove it from the circuit.

This simplification allows us to conclude:

1. \$Q_1\$ is in active mode. It's base-collector junction is reverse-biased and its base-emitter junction is forward-biased. As a consequence, we can take its \$\beta\$ as valid.
2. \$Q_2\$ is in active mode. It's base-collector junction is reverse-biased and its base-emitter junction is forward-biased. As a consequence, we can take its \$\beta\$ as valid.

It then follows that:

- \$\frac{I_{_{\text{C}_2}}}{I_{_{\text{C}_1}}}=\beta+1\$

We know from the Shockley equation (and assuming the emission coefficient or ideality factor is 1) that:

- \$V_{_{\text{BE}_2}}-V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}\approx V_T\cdot\ln\left(\frac{I_{_{\text{C}_2}}}{I_{_{\text{C}_1}}}\right)=V_T\cdot\ln\left(\beta+1\right)\$

So, from KVL, \$V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}+V_{_{\text{BE}_2}}=V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}+V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}+V_T\cdot\ln\left(\beta+1\right)\$.

But that's just \$1\:\text{V}\$.

So:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}+V_{_{\text{BE}_2}}&=1\:\text{V}
\\\\
V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}+V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}+V_T\cdot\ln\left(\beta+1\right)&=1\:\text{V}
\\\\
2\cdot V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}+V_T\cdot\ln\left(\beta+1\right)&=1\:\text{V}
\\\\
V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}&=\frac{1\:\text{V}-V_T\cdot\ln\left(\beta+1\right)}2
\\\\
&=500\:\text{mV}-\frac12\cdot 25.9\:\text{mV}\cdot\ln\left(101\right)
\\\\
&\approx 440.2342\:\text{mV}
\\\\
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\rlap{\text{And so: }}
\\\\
V_{_{\text{BE}_2}}&=V_{_{\text{BE}_1}}+V_T\cdot\ln\left(\beta+1\right)
\\\\
&= 559.7658\:\text{mV}
\end{align*}$$

There's no escaping this analysis, if we assume that \$R_1\$ is bypassed.

So, the only remaining question is whether or not conclusion #2 above remains true if we add back \$R_1\$. Let's test it.

From the above analysis and your given that \$I_{_\text{SAT}}=10\:\text{fA}\$ then if follows that the collector current of \$Q_2\$ is:

$$I_{_{\text{C}_2}}=I_{_\text{SAT}}\cdot\left[\exp\left(\frac{V_{_{\text{BE}_2}}}{V_T}\right)-1\right]=10\:\text{fA}\cdot\left[\exp\left(\frac{559.7658\:\text{mV}}{25.9\:\text{mV}}\right)-1\right]\approx 24.3346\:\mu\text{A}$$

From this, and the fact that \$R_1=100\:\Omega\$, we can conclude that the voltage drop across \$R_1\$ is negligible and doesn't invalidate conclusion #2, above.

Therefore all of the above analysis also holds.